# Creating TK frames then closing one

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to know if it's possible to generate a Tk Frame which asks for some input ( for example where to save a File or the Name of the File ) then close it when the information is given and generate a new one with other inputs.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the `Toplevel` and not the `Frame` widget, and yes you have the option to `withdraw` or `destroy` the window as you see fit.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Please make sure you're using the correct terminology. Are you asking about the `Frame` widget, or are you asking about creating pop-up dialogs?

Comment: Either case here works, so being ambiguous works. But if I had to pick one or the other then it would be more a widget I guess. Since I would prefer having one, then it destroys itself and then generates a new one, which is the one that I already have code for.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the [`.destroy()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destroy-method-in-tkinter-python/) method.

You can call the `.destroy()` method on any [`tk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) widget including Frames and Windows.

More on [`destroy()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/destroy-method-in-tkinter-python) method..

Comment: How can I use that? As in, I will have to duplicate code or is there an easier way to avoid duplicate code?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate code?

Comment: In addition, you didn't specify in the question  if the frame is in a new popup like window or if it is just a part of the window that disappears once you click on a button. So it is hard to give you specific details or example.

Comment: That's true, I thought more of an Initial window that then pops the second one which is the "main" one For example, in the creation of the Tk. upper = Tk()
upper.title("Logger")

root = Tk()
root.title("Logger")

Comment: And you want a value from a file dialog (from the first window) to be transferred to the "main" one?

Comment: "Initial window that  then pops the second one"  Is the second one replacing the first one or in addition to it?

Comment: I will of course use StringVar() and the .get to store it for later

Comment: Replace, as I already have the main code for that one, this "new" one is a add on so to say